# How would I do this in PHP? Form input, then function, then output in div, without page refresh?

Tags: php

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Form submit in php without refresh?</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function processForm() { 
        $.ajax( {
            url: process.php,
            data: 'how to get everything from process.php echos?',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#calc').html(data);
            }
        } );
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" method="post" action="" onsubmit="processForm();return false;">
        <input type="text" id="total" name="total" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" />
    </form>
<div id="calc">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
$number = $_POST['total'];
//this should be $number = "the number entered in the 'total' field in the form";

echo $d = ceil(log(2*$number)/log(3))," tiers<br />\n";
$x = 1;
for($i = 1; $i<$d;$i++){
    echo "tier " . $i . "<br />\n";
    echo str_repeat('o', $x),"<br />\n";
    $number -= $x;
    $x *= 3;
}
echo "tier " . $i . "<br />\n";
echo str_repeat('o', $number),"<br />\n";
//all of the above echos should go into the 'calc' div in html, without page refresh
?>
```

Comment: You're going to need JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things to cover here.

**1) Retrieving POST data.**

You can access the post data from the $_POST array, so in your case you would do `$number = $_POST['total'];`

**2) Ajax call**

Here is a good tutorial on using jQuery for submitting forms without redirect:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

And here is the API for jQuery Ajax methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: @Mike Lewis: Thank you. I have updated my code with my attempt. I'm still unsure how to grab the echo's from the process.php to then insert into the div as 'data' through ajax. `data: 'how to get everything from process.php echos?',`. Is everything else in my code ok?

Comment: Everything else looks good except for the fact that you aren't passing in type as data, thus $_POST['type'] won't be defined.

Comment: @Mike Lewis: so I remove the line `type: 'POST',` as I'm not passing in type.. just the data.. but how do I pass in the specific data from process.php using `data = `?

Comment: For example, if you were to do data: "name=John&location=Boston", you could then access $_POST['name'] and $_POST['location'] in process.php

Comment: @Mike Lewis: Got it. Just I'm not presetting the values, they are grabbed from the user entry in 'total'. Meanwhile it works, thank you - however, it outputs `-INF tiers tier 1`. In process.php I have `$number = $_POST['total'];` and obviously number isn't being set right. How can I fix the code so `$number = TheTotalFieldInTheForm;`?

Comment: you need to set data to something like: data: "type=" + document.getElementById('type').value , from there the value in the form will be submitted.

Comment: @Mike Lewis: or even in JS `data: "total=TheTotalFieldInTheForm"` so `$number = $_POST['total'];` can be left as is in process.php. Unsure how to grab the value of that total field in JS.

Comment: As shown above, you grab the total field in JS by doing document.getElementById("type").value

Comment: @Mike Lewis: Sorry just noticed after. Tried `data: "total=" + document.getElementById('total').value,` and using `$number = $_POST['total'];` in process.php. Still no go. Sorry, JS is a pain for me.

Comment: @Mike Lewis: OOPS, I should be using GET, not POST, ie: `$number = $_GET['total'];` thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do an AJAX call instead of actually doing an HTTP POST. This is done in JavaScript. You then hang code off the return hook to put content in the div.

[jQuery has library calls](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) to make this easier than doing it all manually.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my code with my attempt. I'm still unsure how to grab the echo's from the process.php to then insert into the div as 'data' through ajax. `data: 'how to get everything from process.php echos?',`. Is everything else in my code ok?

Comment: You need to retrieve all the fields you want to send and put them into the `data:` element in the `.ajax` call. (Also put the page name in `url:` in quotes.)

Comment: Good pickup! Thank you - however, it outputs `-INF tiers tier 1`. In process.php I have `$number = $_POST['total'];` and obviously number isn't being set right. How can I fix the code so `$number = TheTotalFieldInTheForm;`?