# Not redirecting when submitting a form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, redirect

I have a simple form which I am validating with jquery livevalidate, and processing with a php script. Instead of redirecting the page once the form is successfully submitted, I would like to display a div using jquery (and stay on the same page).

```
<form action="/process_form.php" method="post">


      <div id="field1-container">
           <label>Name</label>
           <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

             <script type="text/javascript">
                var f1 = new LiveValidation('name');
                f1.add(Validate.Presence);
                f1.add( Validate.Length, { minimum: 4, maximum: 30 } );
              </script>
      </div>


      <div id="field4-container" class="field f_100 twelve columns">
           <label>
                Email Address
           </label>
           <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

               <script type="text/javascript">
                var f2 = new LiveValidation('email');
                f2.add(Validate.Presence);
                f2.add( Validate.Email );
              </script>

      </div>


      <div id="field3-container" class="field f_100 twelve columns">
           <label>Message</label>
           <textarea rows="5" name="message" id="message"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
                var f3 = new LiveValidation('message');
                f3.add(Validate.Presence);
              f3.add( Validate.Length, { minimum: 20, maximum: 300 } );
              </script>

      </div>

<br>

<div id="form-submit">
           <input type="submit" class="small button radius" value="Submit">
</div>

<!-- mymodal div revealed on form success -->

<script type="text/javascript">
if ($("#contactform").valid()) {
        $("#myModal").reveal();
    }
 </script>

</form>
```

And the processing code (process_form.php) is:

```
<? ob_start(); ?>
<?php

$to = "destemail@domain.com \r\n";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$email_from = 'an@email.com';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "Contact via website";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from $name.\n\n".
"Here is the message:\n $message\n\n\n".

$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n"; //Send the email!

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
$injections = array('(\n+)',
          '(\r+)',
          '(\t+)',
          '(%0A+)',
          '(%0D+)',
          '(%08+)',
          '(%09+)'
          );
$inject = join('|', $injections);
$inject = "/$inject/i";
if(preg_match($inject,$str))
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}

?> 

<? ob_flush(); ?>
```

The div '#mymodal' shows up, but then the page redirects to the php file... how can I stop it doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would I do this in PHP? Form input, then function, then output in div, without page refresh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386531/how-would-i-do-this-in-php-form-input-then-function-then-output-in-div-witho)

Comment: Literally wrote an answer to something like this just now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19370177/292735

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be preventing the submission, unless I missed it.

You would want to write some javascript that prevents the default action onsubmit, and instead uses AJAX to send the form data to your processor PHP script. The php returns whatever it is you want to return and the AJAX displays it in your modal window.

I'd start with looking at Javascript's preventDefault and the JQUERY library's .ajax function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the form is checked for validity with the livevalidate plugin, which doesn't allow the form to be submitted if there is an error, and if it returns no errors, then the popup (and the redirection) occur. I'll look into .ajax :)

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, I was kind of skimming. It sounds like you don't want the redirection, you just want the results to show in a modal div?