# Ajax form submission

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery

I am using ajax to submit a html input form and to redirect the output page when it is done.  I tried two approaches but not sure why their results are different.

HTML form is something looks like this:

```
<form id="output_post" method="post" action="output.html">
    <table class="input"></table>
</form>
```

Approach 1:

```
    var frm = $('#output_post');
    frm.submit()
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        success: function (url) {
            window.location = "/output.html"
        }
    });
```

Approach 2:

```
    var frm = $('#output_post');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        success: function(url) {
            window.location = "/output.html"
        }

    });
```

Approach 1 worked as I expected but I got error message in Approach 2 `405 Method Not Allowed The method GET is not allowed for this resource.` The difference between Approaches 1 and 2 is `frm.submit()`, and I am very sure both approaches have successfully initiate calculation.

Could anyone give me some hints on this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Does your AJAX call actually run in the first approach? You can test by adding an `alert` before the `window.location` line. I believe submitting a form should stop execution of all JS on the page as you're sending a request for another page.

Comment: @Jasper: Yes you are right. It seems like `ajax` call did not run in the first method. After removing `frm.submit()` Approaches 1 and 2 generate the same 405 errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your server apparently isn't setup to handle POST requests. Try changing the `type` to `get` and see if you get the same error. If you don't get the same error, look into how to setup your server software (technology stack) to properly handle POST requests.

Comment: @Jasper I think the server can handle POST. Because when I included `frm.submit()` which created a post request and it worked...

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting an error when the form submits normally (without AJAX)? In Chrome you can watch your network tab to see what exactly is being returned as a response from the server after submitting the form. See if you're getting a 405 response code there.

Comment: @Jasper: It worked with only `frm.submit()`. Here is the Chrome tab info: `Request URL:http://localhost:8080/output.html
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK`

Comment: Interesting, that's about all that came to my mind. I've never seen this error code before. Good luck with finding the answer, and if you do, please post it here for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would actually say `.submit()` would be better reserved for *allowing* the Browser to actually go ahead with the natural/indented behaviour of following through to the `action=""` - if you wanted to actually have a different 'end result' - that's where [`$.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) comes into help.

```
/**
 *   $.submit will listen to
 *   the .submit event, preventing
 *   default and allowing us to mimic
 *   the submission process and have our
 *   bespoke end result.
**/
$('#output_post').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var getValues = $(this).serialize();
    $.post( 'yourScript.php', getValues, function() {
        window.location.href = "/output.html";
    } 
});
```

### Comments to the Question

> **Approach One**

- This 'leaves' the function. Prematurely sending you away from the page before it's allowed to execute the rest of the script. The native `.submit()` will follow through to the action, which is the indented behaviour. Thus, `$.ajax` never ran.

> **Approach Two**

- Servers could/can decide on it's accepted content types.
- No Data was sent to the `URL`, thus - defaulted to `GET` (Despite type: `POST`) But there's no serialised. array given.
- This may 'act' different if you define 'data: values' in Approach Two.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explain. I doubled checked my code and it seems like the issue (maybe) related in the selection of `dataType`. If possible, would you mind taking a look at this post?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372808/ajax-submit-form-datatype-issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var frm = $('#output_post');

$('#output_post').submit(function(event) {

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        success: function(url) {
            window.location = "/output.html"
        }

    });

});
```

-
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I still get the same issue.

Comment: I checked the log and it seems like the console.log(url) has my output page. But the redirection breaks it.