# Ajax submit form datatype issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am having some problems about using ajax to submit a html input form, and it seems like something is wrong with the `datatype`.

The background:

1. sending an input form from `app engine` to `aws`
2. creating a `pdf` file on `aws`, saving it on `s3`, and sending back the hyperlink to `app engine`
3. on `app engine` side, generating a html page with the hyperlink
4. if the ajax call is successful, redirect to the page created on `Step 3`

Input form:

```
<form id="pdf_post">
    <table class="getpdf popup">
        <!-- contents include 1. string type html table and jqplots -->
    </table>
</form>
```

Ajax call:

```
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        alert('start');
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/pdf.html",
        data: $('#pdf_post').serialize(),
        dataType: "html",
        success: function () {
            alert('success');
            window.location = "/pdf.html";
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            alert('error');
        },
    });
```

Based on the `ajax` call, my browser will be redirected to a page with hyperlink. But this never happened, and the results are related to values in the `dataType`:

1. `dataType: "html"`, `ajax` success fired, but I got error msg: `405 Method Not Allowed The method GET is not allowed for this resource.`
2. `dataType: "json"`, `ajax` error fired
3. `dataType: "data"`, `ajax` error fired

I have checked the server side, it seem like a pdf was always generated no matter what dataType I selected. Also when `ajax error` was fired, from the `console.log(data)`, I can see the webpage with the correct hyperlink. Can anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: It's likely that /pdf.html can't be accessed thru HTTP get which is what you are doing when the data was posted successfully. Should you really redirect to /pdf.html (window.location = "/pdf.html")?

Comment: Maybe what you want is: success: function (data) { ..do something with the HTML data.. }

Comment: @LostInComputer: Thanks for the comment. When I change everything to `get`, under the `network` tab, if I double click the `pdf.html`, it brings me to the right page (but this activity is considered another request to the server). While if I use `post`, double click will end up with a 405 error.